# For a connecting flight in Kiev, do I need a transit visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, transit-visas, layovers, ukraine

I am an Indian national and traveling to Latvia via Kiev, Ukraine. I have a 5.5-hour layover. Do I need a transit visa there? I hold a Schengen visa.

Comment: Where are you travelling from?

Comment: Delhi to latvia

Comment: @ZympleXBuildersPvtLtd What passport are you traveling on? Questions about visa requirements are generally dependent first and foremost on your citizenship.

Comment: I own an indian passport

Comment: Please help me as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://kbp.aero/en/pass/transfer/), 'International to international' section says nothing about passport check. If you google for something like 'kbp transit visa', most results ([often notably old](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294474-i3663-k6628249-4_hours_transit_at_airport_do_i_need_a_visa-Kiev.html)) suggest you don't need a visa if you don't change terminals (if the terminal you arrive at and depart from is the same, and if it is terminal D).

You might probably want to contact the airport (the first link I gave displays phone numbers on the top of the page) and/or the nearest Ukraine consulate for a better clarification.